# Display user defined number of MySql results with dynamicly updating content [php]

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to limit the number of rows that the page shows according to the users selection from a drop down(think like a store page "show number of items per page")

At the moment I'm using php to call MySql and then echo out my results. I know that php cant do anything after the page loads. The next thing that comes to mind is java script. 
However I have no experience with java script, I'm fair *normal* with java.

What are other options that you would suggest?
note:  *I want to limit my while loop not the mysql result.*

Here is my code as it stands now:

```
<form name="input" action="EditPartyP.php" method="post">
<tr> 
    <td>Party ID</td><td>Party Name</td>
    <td>Start Date</td><td>End Date</td><td>Sales</td><td>VIEW:
```

The drop down selection options that are being offered.

```
<select>
   <option value="10">10</option>
   <option value="20">20</option>
   <option value="40">40</option>
   <option value="80">80</option>
</select>

   </td>
```

The results from the query being displayed, I under stand that I will have to change this because the php is done when the user sees the output html.

```
<?php
     $ID = $_SESSION['ID'];
     $result = PartyData::PartyLookupByID($_SESSION['ID'], "DESC");
```

This loop now just runs until the result runs out of data.
I need to make it stop when the users number is reached as well.

```
     while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
     echo "<tr>";
     echo '<form name="input" action="EditPartyP.php" method="post">';

    echo "<td>" . $row['PartyID'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['PartyName'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['sDate'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['eDate'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['PartyOrderTotal'] . " </td>";
    echo '<input type="hidden" value=" ' . $row['PartyID'] . '" name="PartyID">';

    echo "<td>" . '<button type="submit" value="Edit" name="Action">Edit</button>' . "</td>";

    echo '</form>';
    echo "</tr>";
    }
?>
</table>
```

Thank you for reading and a comment helps more than a down vote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to look into https://datatables.net if you want features such as per page row diaplay or so called pagination.

Comment: That link is helpful  but still lacks the information I need to use it quickly. 
But, I do think that it add the functionality I need.

Comment: Actually, the documentation is very good and it has plugin for future expansion. You only need to build a table and apply the jquery to the table and you're ready to roll.

Comment: Would you suggest that I try to move to AJAX? rather than my Html and php mess?

Comment: I have problem with DataTables my css isn't working with the rendered table. its putting it at the bottom of the page just before the footer.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the selected page (via a $_GET['var'] and the users choice of number of records per page, you have to adjust your query with the limit statement.

```
SELECT * FROM table LIMIT 10, 50
```

Would start at the 10th record and will select 50 records max.

Comment: I want to limit my while loop not the mysql result.

Comment: And also I'm tring to accomplish this with out reloading the page.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SQL Limit command to retrieve specific number of data.

SELECT column_name(s) FROM table_name LIMIT number;

Comment: you are missing my point... or I didn't state it clearly. 
I want to limit my while loop not the mysql result.

Comment: then use while loop like this.

$i = 1;
while ($i <= 10) {
    echo $i++;  
}

Comment: yes Yes, but how do I pass the value through without reloading the page.

Comment: You should reload when a user changes it, AJAX is a very good technique to do that with.

Comment: Okay, I will do it that way then and just refresh the page with the new data. I was just trying to avoid making the page more complicated. How would AJAX  integrate in the my site as it is now?